# Approaches to limiting parallel executions

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

When it comes to throttling parallel execution what is the difference between the following two approaches? Or is one preferred over the other?

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4};
Parallel.ForEach(collection, parallelOptions, item =>
{
    // ...
});
```

and

```
Task ThrottleParallelWorkAsync(IEnumerable<T> data, Action<T> worker)
{
    TaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
        TaskScheduler.Default,          // schedule work to the ThreadPool
        Environment.ProcessorCount * 2) // Schedule enough to keep all threads busy, with a queue to quickly replace completed work
        .ConcurrentScheduler;           // We only use the concurrent member of this scheduler "pair".

    return Task.WhenAll(
        data.Select(v => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => worker(v), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler)));
}
```

The second approach is described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2017/05/11/limiting-concurrency-for-faster-and-more-responsive-apps/

Comment: I believe the difference is: the first one defines how many tasks will be in *execution* simultaneously, while second defines the size of Task buffer where ready to process Tasks are stored, *waiting* for their execution.

Comment: The two snippets do *very* different things. In fact, the DOP in the first case isn't needed as `Parallel.ForEach` *does* take the core count into account. `Parallel.For/ForEach` are meant for *data* parallelism scenarios. They use roughly as many tasks as cores, they partition the input and ensure each task always has work. They will *increase* or *decrease* the number of tasks if the'res an imbalance. They'll also use the current thread for processing which is why they appear to block.

Comment: The second snippet on the other hand doesn't partition the data and spawns one task per data item (which have to be gc'd afterwards), but tries to throttle their execution. It *oversubscribes*, which should only be useful for IO, not data bound tasks. Frankly, I'd rather use an ActionBlock<T> if I only wanted to limit the number of concurrent executions

Comment: You have configured the first approach with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4`, and the second approach with `maxConcurrencyLevel = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2`. Given that you are attempting to compare two different APIs, why are you configuring them with different values? The two approaches have different behavior, partly because they are different APIs, and partly because they are configured with different values, and you can't say easily which is which. You'll learn more from an experiment if you change one variable at a time.